# Insert variable in array if not present

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to insert variables in an array. I am using `in_array()` function to check if a value has already been inserted and `array_push` to append elements to the array.

**Working example**

```
<?php 
$var1="cat";
$var2="dog";
$var3="gepp";
$var4="frigor";
$var5="dog";
$var6='cat';

$array1=array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6);

$ya=array();

for($i=0;$i<=count($ya);$i++)
{
 if (in_array($array1[$i],$ya,true))
 {          
    echo $i . " : Yess<br>";
 }
 else
 { 
    array_push($ya, $array1[$i]);
    echo $i . " : Noo<br>";
 }
}

echo "<br>\n";
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>\n";
print_r($ya);
?>
```

The output is:

> 0 : Noo
>   1 : Noo 
>   2 : Noo 
>   3 : Noo 
>   4 : Yess
>
> Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog [2] => gepp [3] => frigor [4] => dog [5] => cat )
>   Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog [2] => gepp [3] => frigor )

**Not working example**

In the following code values are saved from the label tag of an xml.

```
$array = array();
foreach($mypix->result as $pixinfo):
    echo " Result<br>\n   ";
    foreach($pixinfo->row as $row): 
        $label=$row->label;         
        if (in_array($label,$array,true))
        {           
            echo "Yess<br>";
        }
        else
        { 
            array_push($array, $label);
            echo "No<br>";
        }
        echo "[NEXT]<br>\n";
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

The xml's structure is as follows:

```
<result date="2014-05-05"> 
  <row> 
    <label>1.1</label> 
    <nb_visits>4</nb_visits> 
  </row> 
</result> 
<result date="2014-05-06"/> 
<result date="2014-05-08"> 
  <row> 
    <label>Custom Variable value not defined</label> 
    <nb_visits>115</nb_visits> 
    <nb_actions>261</nb_actions> 
  </row> 
  <row> 
    <label>Commedia</label> 
    <nb_visits>26</nb_visits>
    <nb_actions>39</nb_actions> 
  </row> 
[...]
</result>
```

The problem is that values are inserted even if they are already present in the array.
Do you guys have any advice? What's wrong with the `in_array` command?

**Edit**

Here is the output of `var_dump($array);`

```
array(441){
[0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "1.1" } 
[1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "1.2" } 
[2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "1.1" } 
[3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "1.1" } 
[4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) { [0]=> string(33) "Custom Variable value not defined" }
```

Comment: I would use array_diff to locate the differences - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Maybe they have differences in whitespace.

Comment: can you post the output of `var_dump($array)`

Comment: Please post it in the question with proper formatting.

Comment: That's an array of objects, not an array of strings.

Comment: Is there an equivalent function of `in_array()` for arrays of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_unique to cut reapating variables or array_diff to find difference between 2 arrays

Comment: The original array is a multidimensional array of objects, and he's just extracting one field of the objects. So `array_diff()` can't be used.

Comment: With `$result = array_unique($array);` I am able to get the correct count of different values inserted but the resulting array has blank entries.

The problem remains...what's wrong with `in_array()` command?